# Unable to determine cause of "ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

When I issue this create table statement, Oracle raises ORA-00906 "missing left parenthesis" but I'm unable to determine why.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHOOL
(

WELFARE_TYPE VARCHAR2(20),
ESTABLISHMENT_DATE DATE,

SCHOOL_NAME VARCHAR2(20),

DONATION_FUND VARCHAR2(20),
TOTAL_TEACHER NUMBER (10,0),
TOTAL_STUDENTS NUMBER(10,0),
CONSTRAINT SCHOOL_SCHOOL_NAME_UK UNIQUE KEY (SCHOOL_NAME),
CONSTRAINT WELFARE_TYPE_PK PRIMARY KEY (WELFARE_TYPE)
);
```

Comment: Please provide a complete description of the issue instead of just giving a chunk of code.

Comment: THERE'S NO `UNIQUE KEY`, JUST `UNIQUE`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJADJGEC

Answer (score 3):

You need to take out the word "key" when setting up the unique constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHOOL
(

WELFARE_TYPE VARCHAR2(20),
ESTABLISHMENT_DATE DATE,

SCHOOL_NAME VARCHAR2(20),

DONATION_FUND VARCHAR2(20),
TOTAL_TEACHER NUMBER (10,0),
TOTAL_STUDENTS NUMBER(10,0),
CONSTRAINT SCHOOL_SCHOOL_NAME_UK UNIQUE (SCHOOL_NAME),
CONSTRAINT WELFARE_TYPE_PK PRIMARY KEY (WELFARE_TYPE)
);
```